# How to grab remote latest maven tar.gz file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to install `maven` in my docker container . This is my Dockerfile :

```
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN wget http://ftp.twaren.net/Unix/Web/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
RUN ln -s ../apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn .
```

The problem is :

1. I hope it will find the nearest server reported by https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi , not this hard-coded `http://ftp.twaren.net/`
2. I don't want to hard-coded version 3.3.3 in the Dockerfile , I hope some way to analyze https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi , and get the latest version. Is there anyway to parse/dom-select in Dockerfile ?
3. You may ask why not just `yum install maven` ? Because I've install jdk8 , but maven in the `epel` repository is dependent on jdk7 , which will install older version and set it to default.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For 2 you can see how I get the latest version of a sofware (captvty), i  short `RUN version=$(wget -q -O- http://captvty.fr/ | grep -o -m 1 'captvty-.*.zip' | sed 's/captvty-\(.*\).zip/\1/') && wget -O /dev/null http://captvty.fr/ && wget -O /tmp/Captvty.zip http://captvty.fr/?captvty-$version.zip && unzip -d  ~/Captvty /tmp/Captvty.zip && rm /tmp/Captvty.zip`  from the Dockerfile you can see at https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1809831

Answer (score 1):

> I hope it will find the nearest server reported by https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi , not this hard-coded http://ftp.twaren.net/

I just copied what they did for the [official maven image](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/882a21728d702dad08279afe6b6bf9fa4b8bfe18/jdk-7/Dockerfile). That will at least get you downloading from something more official instead of a random mirror. Won't solve the proximity issue necessarily though.

> I don't want to hard-coded version 3.3.3 in the Dockerfile...

Few things here. Most directly related to your question you can write something to parse that info out yourself and use that in your Dockerfile. This will be complicated and likely brittle however.

I'd argue that baking the maven version into the build is actually a good thing. That way your build is repeatable (and simple). If it grabbed the latest version at build time then the version of maven you got would be out of your control. That would make it difficult when you wanted to publish your image because you wouldn't easily know how to tag it. e.g. is it `my-maven:3.3.3` or `my-maven:3.3.4`? You could also no longer tie a particular version of your maven image to a version of your Dockerfile.

All that said, Docker 1.9 is getting a [--build-arg](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15182) flag what will allow you to specify variables to use in your `Dockerfile` at build time. This way you could pass in what maven version you want to build into your image without having to modify the `Dockerfile`. Sounds like this would make your life easier as well.

Hope this all helps!